# How do I build a class to deserialize following Json into?

Tags: c#, json, restsharp

I have the following Json:

```
  {
    "BTC_BCN": {
    "id": 7,
    "last": "0.00000091",
    "lowestAsk": "0.00000091",
    "highestBid": "0.00000090",
    "percentChange": "-0.16513761",
    "baseVolume": "7448.24465884",
    "quoteVolume": "8447512040.11460590",
    "isFrozen": "0",
    "high24hr": "0.00000115",
    "low24hr": "0.00000071"
},
"BTC_BELA": {
    "id": 8,
    "last": "0.00009098",
    "lowestAsk": "0.00009178",
    "highestBid": "0.00009101",
    "percentChange": "0.02918552",
    "baseVolume": "143.21212880",
    "quoteVolume": "1621911.96303103",
    "isFrozen": "0",
    "high24hr": "0.00009196",
    "low24hr": "0.00008681"
},
"BTC_BLK": {
    "id": 10,
    "last": "0.00010199",
    "lowestAsk": "0.00010262",
    "highestBid": "0.00010204",
    "percentChange": "0.03859470",
    "baseVolume": "51.34937066",
    "quoteVolume": "512481.76267599",
    "isFrozen": "0",
    "high24hr": "0.00010752",
    "low24hr": "0.00009375"
    }
```

}

I want to create structures like the following:

```
public class QuoteDetail
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string last { get; set; }
    public string lowestAsk { get; set; }
    public string highestBid { get; set; }
    public string percentChange { get; set; }
    public string baseVolume { get; set; }
    public string quoteVolume { get; set; }
    public string isFrozen { get; set; }
    public string high24hr { get; set; }
    public string low24hr { get; set; }
}

public class Quote
{
   public string SymbolName {get; set;}
   public QuoteDetail QuoteDetail {get; set;}
}
```

What i want is a List of Quotes with symbol name containing BTC_BCN for example, and the quote details containing the individual fields.

The only thing i can get to work is creating separate classes for each of the symbol names....not what I need.

I'm using RestSharp.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the current structure of the JSON, first convert it to a dictionary to get the `SymbolName` as the key. From there simply perform a linq projection on the dictionary passing the `key` as the `SymbolName` and the `value` as the `QuoteDetails`.

```
var dictionary = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IDictionary<string, QuoteDetail>>(json);

var quotes = dictionary
    .Select(kvp => new Quote { SymbolName = kvp.Key, QuoteDetail = kvp.Value })
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have almost done everything. Just create the following class:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public QuoteDetail BTC_BCN { get; set; }
    public QuoteDetail BTC_BELA { get; set; }
    public QuoteDetail BTC_BLK { get; set; }
}
```

And using [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) nuget package do the following:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(jsonString);
```

Comment: The problem is, I don't want separate fields for each quote, I want a list of quotedetails with the quote name as  a  string

Comment: @shuri17 than your json is not correct as you have anonymous class with 3 properties and not array of object

Answer (score 0):

Create class structure from JSON with the help of http://json2csharp.com. Since you have same structure for all class like BTC_BCN, BTC_BELA, BTC_BLK than use only single class with common name and create a property with required name for example

```
     public class ObjectData
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string last { get; set; }
        public string lowestAsk { get; set; }
        public string highestBid { get; set; }
        public string percentChange { get; set; }
        public string baseVolume { get; set; }
        public string quoteVolume { get; set; }
        public string isFrozen { get; set; }
        public string high24hr { get; set; }
        public string low24hr { get; set; }
    }


    public class RootObject
    {
        public ObjectData BTC_BCN { get; set; }
        public ObjectData BTC_BELA { get; set; }
        public ObjectData BTC_BLK { get; set; }
    }
```

than deserialize your object
RootObject rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonData);